# printing using for loop in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, csv, for-loop, scripting

I have 2 files with multiple fields. File A is dynamic which has users logged in everyday and their login times and date. File B has the total number of users and their airport codes. File B is a static file. I need to print the File A data along with the airportcodes of the users. I used the below script..

```
A=`cut -d " " -f1 /data/sampleupdatedreport.csv`
for A
do
grep $A /home/s399682/StarUsers.txt >tmp_today.csv
done
```

It is not working. Please help me to find a solution for this. Thanks very much in advance!!!

Comment: It would be helpful to show some sample data from the 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

Your *script* can be written as:

```
grep -f <(cut -d " " -f1 /data/sampleupdatedreport.csv) /home/s399682/StarUsers.txt >tmp_today.csv
```

This would match all lines in `/home/s399682/StarUsers.txt` that match the output produced by the `cut` command.

---

If you really wanted to write a script, you could say:

```
while read -r line; do
  grep "$line" /home/s399682/StarUsers.txt
done < <(cut -d " " -f1 /data/sampleupdatedreport.csv) > tmp_today.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)...